# Moving Wordpress site to new server same URL

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to move a wordpress site to a new database on a new server, because the old host is no longer running. I have a new database on the new server, new name, username, pw, etc. and changed all that info in the wp-config.php file. I don't want to change the url. But when I type that url into the browser, its asking me to do an install of wordpress all over again. Is this right?

Comment: Are you simply changing hosts? Or are you changing the domain, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use phpmyadmin on the new host to check the table prefixes of the imported database. The "new install" issue means wp-config.php isn't reading the correct database tables. Or, open the database dump and check the database table prefix.

And, of course, be sure your database name, user and password are all correct in the new wp-config.php.

If you are not changing the domain, there is no need to change URLs in the database. If you do change domains, use http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ to correctly change URLs in plain and serialized data.